# How can I draw a barplot in r based on numeric threshold?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I have a barplot like the following. Now I want the the color of a column to be red if it is below 0 and green if it is above 0. How can I do that in R?
[image]

Comment: please post full code to reproduce the plot

Comment: Mark posted a solution. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just made another variable that categorized a value as either above zero or not:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1839)
df <- data.frame(x=factor(1:5), y=rnorm(5,0,2))
df$zero <- factor(ifelse(df$y>0, 1, 0))
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=zero)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("red", "green"), guide=FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Aah, that makes sense. Thanks!